# Views exposed filters set per content type in same view

Tags: views

Sorry for my fuzzy title. The problem I have is that I have a view that lists 2 different content types. Now I want to use a filter that will only filter on ONE of the content types that is listed.

Say I have one content type named "Album", and one content type named "Songs" that gets listed in the same view. Now I still need to have them both listed in the same view, but I want to add the filter "First letter is A" to the songs ONLY.
So the Albums gets listed as before, but the songs that doesn't start with the letter A is removed.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a filter that filters on content type for **Album**
2. Create a filter that filters on content type for **Songs**
3. Create a filter that filters on title (set it to exposed and set the operator to "Starts with"
4. Under Filter Criteria instead of add, click on the arrow and choose "And/Or, Rearrange"
5. Click "Create new filter group"
6. Now drag the filter created in step 2 and 3 to the new group (Songs and Title)
7. Make sure the operator between the filter groups is OR and the operators between the filters in a group are set to AND

Your filters should look like
[image]

Comment: Hahaha ofc! I've totally forgot this. Thanks you! I'll try it this way and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Now I've bounce into another problem. I want to use a contextual filter, this also on just ONE of the listed contenttypes. I want it to list one of the contenttypes that is referenced on the current node, and the other contenttype should get listed ALL of them. Any ideas?

Comment: If the answer provided was helpful to you it would be nice to mark it as accepted :) http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Ofcource, sorry ^^ But I'm not totally sure if it will work with this solution anyway, with my other problem in mind.

Comment: Well ok but that other problem was not in the original question :) Perhaps it's better to ask a new question.